# Beginner issue: cannot navigate in a child route with the proper component

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am developing a small Angular material application. I use a routing module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppProduitImmobilierDetailsComponent} from './app-produit-immobilier-details/app-produit-immobilier-details.component';
import { AppListProduitImmobilierComponent } from './app-list-produit-immobilier/app-list-produit-immobilier.component';

const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/listproduitimmobilier',
    pathMatch: 'full' }, {
      path: 'listproduitimmobilier',
      component: AppListProduitImmobilierComponent,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'details/:id',
          component: AppProduitImmobilierDetailsComponent
        }
      ]
  }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,
      { enableTracing: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I import it in AppModule

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { MaterialModule } from './material/material.module';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppProduitImmobilierDetailsComponent } from './app-produit-immobilier-details/app-produit-immobilier-details.component';
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
import 'hammerjs';
import { AppListProduitImmobilierComponent } from './app-list-produit-immobilier/app-list-produit-immobilier.component';
enableProdMode();
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AppProduitImmobilierDetailsComponent,
    AppListProduitImmobilierComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

in AppListProduitImmobilierComponent, i navigate to the child route corresponding to the AppProduitImmobilierDetailsComponent component

```
   goToDetailsView(annonce: ProduitImmobilierDTO) {
      this.router.navigate(['/listproduitimmobilier/details/' + annonce.id]);
    }
```

but instead of going to the child route corresponding to AppProduitImmobilierDetailsComponent component, it stays on the parent view corresponding to AppListProduitImmobilierComponent. However, the url is

```
http://localhost:4200/listproduitimmobilier/details/1
```

which is the child view url. Could you help me ?

Comment: Given that the details route is a child of the list route, that's expected: you're supposed to have a router-outlet directive in the template of the list view, and that's where the details view will be displayed. If you want to leave the list view, then the details route shouldn't be a child of the list route.

Comment: Thanks a lot JB Nizet, it resolved the issue. Now it works